# gnuplot gif i generate is just an empty picture

Tags: output, gnuplot, gif

I have a set of text files which contain two sets of numerical data, the files are of the form part(i).txt (without the brackets, they re just for clarity) where i runs from 1 to 9. When i input the following commands into gnuplot everything is fine, I don t get any errors. Fast forward to the last line the gif I get isn t an animation at all it s just empty. Does anyone understand what I m doing wrong.

```
set terminal gif animate delay 100
set output "animation.gif"
do for [i=1:9]{plot sprintf("part%d.txt",i) u 1:2 pt 0}
```

Comment: did you close gnuplot and open the file animation.gif ?

Comment: seems i was wrong i do get a gif file, but the file doesn t do anything it s just empty

Comment: i ll edit the question then, feel kinda stupid now

Comment: "pt 0" is a 1-pixel dot.  Perhaps the dots are simply too small to see?  Try "pt 7" instead.

Comment: What does "empty" mean? A file with size of 0 kB or a graph which shows "nothing"? In the first case I would add a line `set output` at the end.

Comment: it showed nothing, the suggestion to change to pt 7 helped, thanks a lot